# How to capture an XML node while parsing with SAX

Tags: java, xml, dom, saxparser

I'm working on a Java Web Start distributor application. It uses a configuration XML which defines how to serve resources to clients. There are some resources which are generated during the requests. I'm processing the main configuration file with a custom SAXParser handler.

In the configuration file i would like to add an embedded XML definition part which has the servable XML document's root node as a child node.

For example:

```
<Resources>
  <!-- other resource definitions -->
  <EmbeddedXMLResource mapsForRequest="embedded.xml">
    <HiThere>
      <ThisIsAnEmbeddedXMLDocument/>
    </HiThere>
  </EmbeddedXMLResource>
  <!-- ... -->
</Resources>
```

I'm wondering if there's any way of reading the `<HiThere>` node to a DOM document or at least capture the inner contents of `<EmbeddedXMLResource>` into a String skipping the SAX processing?

I thought about putting the embedded content into a CDATA section. This way i can read the embedded XML as a text node but i'll lose syntax highlighting in editors on embedded nodes.

Comment: Why are you using a SAX parser to start with? SAX is efficient in terms of memory for huge documents, but for a configuration file it's overkill, and a much harder API to use than various other ones.

Comment: I have to traverse through the whole XML anyway because i'm constructing different classes from the nodes. I thought a SAX parser is better for this.

Comment: Have you looked at vtd-xml? it seems a much better fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps...

1. On startElement HiThere get the start position in file with the locator
2. On endElement HiThere get the end position also.
3. Open the xml resource with an other Reader, and extract the relevant part as string, and so on.

Funny.

Comment: I haven't found an easier solution, so i accept your answer. Didn't try it out though, rewrote it to use DOM parser instead. Thanks, anyway.